# Firefox Developer Edtion Don't show a icon in menu bar and task bar of Ubuntu. Even changing the .desktop file in /usr/share/application

Tags: command-line, bash, firefox, settings, desktop-icons

I want to install a Firefox dev in bash, but I see this problem with an icon in the GNOME shell.

If open the normal Firefox, in the top bar appears a grayscale icon:

[image]

If you can help me I would appreciate that, thank you!

This is an image showing the problem, this icon of steam is the binary icon, how can I change it?

[image]

I tried to change the `Icon=Path` of your icon, but this is insufficient for changing the icon after running the application, as you can see in the top section. But the icon be changed in the Super menu or after you put in favorites.

Comment: Could you place your solution into the 'Answer' sction of this page rather than append it to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just posting the [OP's](https://askubuntu.com/users/1762015/odavidcesar) answer which was posted in the question. I have edited the question and I hope it might help others.

---

After I made a post in Stack Overflow, but here is the best way to do it,

Today I tried to delete all firefox-devedition from my Linux, and reinstall by apt/Debian following those [tutorials](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2023/11/firefox-developer-edition-and-beta-try-out-mozillas-deb-package/) but this doesn't change anything.

```
odavidcesar@odavidcesar:/usr/share/applications$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install firefox-devedition
Hit:1 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:2 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]
Hit:3 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease   
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                          
Hit:5 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla InRelease                                  
Fetched 119 kB in 1s (98,8 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  firefox-devedition
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/67,1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 247 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package firefox-devedition.
(Reading database ... 209349 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../firefox-devedition_122.0b9~build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking firefox-devedition (122.0b9~build1) ...
Setting up firefox-devedition (122.0b9~build1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
```

After I test install another .deb browser like vivaldi, and it works right.

[image: This image show the Vivaldi icon correctly]